# Laravel 5, log DB::table insert, update , delete events

Tags: laravel, logging, laravel-5.1, dbtable

I am developing Laravel 5 app. In Which I want to log DB::table insert, update and deleted event with all New or changed(in case DB::table is being updated) DB::table Fields . I want simple reusable solution without writing too much of a code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events).

You can bind events for all models you want globally using Service Provider:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        User::creating(function ($user) {
            // Do logging
        });
    }
```

Comment: thank,but i'm using DB::table for insert,update,delete data. in eloquent event it success , but how it in DB::table?

Comment: @DayatFadila, almost same principle. Doom5 gave you a link to Query Events: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#listening-for-query-events

Answer (score 0):

You can use DB::listen() as stated in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#listening-for-query-events).

```
// in your AppServiceProvider
public function boot()
{
    DB::listen(function ($query) {
        // $query->sql
        // $query->bindings
        // $query->time
    });
}
```